# ListView using custom Adapter is overwritten when also adding buttons to the xml file

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am attempting to show a list of items (each entry containing 3 textviews) followed by some buttons that will switch to other activities on click, where similar setups exist. While the ListView is populated perfectly when buttons aren't involved, as soon as I try to add buttons it disappears. I think this may be to do with my having set up the music_list.xml file as exclusively for the list, but from looking at other sources it should be possible to have a ListView followed by other Views. Currently the text button doesn't do anything; I'm trying to get it to show up with the ListView before writing any logic out.

My music_list.xml file, where there is a list and hopefully buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/music_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My music_item file, which holds the 3 TextViews that are used to populate the list;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    tools:text="lutti" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="one" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/album_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    tools:text="one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the current logic for an activity page, which populates the list but doesn't yet do anything to the buttons that are meant to be underneath it:

```
package com.example.android.musicapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ~ Adam ~ on 1/2/2018.
 */

public class MyMusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music_list);


        ArrayList<Music> music = new ArrayList<Music>();

        music.add(new Music("The Who", "Won't Get Fooled Again", "Who's Next"));
        music.add(new Music("A Great Big World", "There's an Answer", "Is there Anybody Out There?"));
        music.add(new Music("James Blake", "Retrograde", "Overgrown"));
        music.add(new Music("Chopin", "Ballade No.3 in A Flat, Op.47", "Chopin: Ballades"));
        music.add(new Music("Kendrick Lamar", "Loyalty (Feat. Rihanna)", "DAMN."));
        music.add(new Music("Schel", "When the Dragon Came Down", "Schel"));
        music.add(new Music("Man man", "Loot My Body", "On Oni Pond"));
        music.add(new Music("Sarah Jarosz", "Dark Road", "Build Me Up From Bones"));
        music.add(new Music("Jimmy Buffett", "Come Monday", "Songs You Know By Heart"));

        MusicAdapter adapter = new MusicAdapter(this, music);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.music_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: apply the weight property to the horizontal-linearlayout instead of button

Comment: you are trying to add buttons in the first layout where you have listview ?. right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `buttons` in your first `layout` that layout pushes your `listview` `layout` to the left so that's why you are unable to see your `list`. Try using `relativeLayout` or put your `linearLayout` correctly. I have used `RelativeLayout` and it is working fine now:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/music_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It looks like I misunderstood the wrap_content and match_parent tags as well as the layout_weight. It is working now.

Comment: @AdamRubin Glad I could be of any help. Yes the main problem was you were giving wrong weights and match_parent as width . Happy Coding :)